# Checking for NaNs in asm.js code

Tags: javascript, mozilla, ieee-754, spidermonkey, asm.js

How can I efficiently check in asm.js code whether a floating point value is a NaN?

A way that works in principle is to import the global `isNaN` JavaScript function as a foreign function into the asm.js module. As calling foreign function is expensive, though, so this won't yield optimal code.

Comparing to the value NaN (which is part of the standard library) is no option because the comparision of a NaN to another NaN always yields false by JavaScript semantics.

Examining bits on the heap is also no option because the endianess is not specified.

Why is `isNaN` not part of the standard library in asm.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property of NaN is commonly used to identify it :

```
var isNaN = a!=a;
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) :

> The equality and inequality predicates are non-signaling so x = x
>   returning false can be used to test if x is a quiet NaN

Comment: When you wrote `x = x`, did you mean `x == x`?

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon I quoted Wikipedia. In JS, yes, it would be `x == x` but NaN isn't specific to a language, that's why it used the standard Math notation instead of the one of C family languages.

Comment: More precisely, the Wikipedia sentence would be translated in JS in `var isNaN = (x==x)==false;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (value !== value) {
    // Definitely NaN
}
```

You can make it as a function like this

```
function isNaN(inputValue) {
    return inputValue !== inputValue;
}
```